# NestJS 8 Socket.io 4 have socket on the server side but not being reached

Tags: socket.io, nestjs

NestJS 8， socket.io 4

1. Client user has a socket being able to receive data from the server. Not sending.
2. Refresh browser, the socket ID changed. Socket on the client receive 'connect' event! Yet. On server side, no logging at all. Which kind of explained point 1.

After reboot nest, problem is gone. But it comes back eventually.

My current troubleshooting direction is

1. Was the connection on the client dead already and it's still trying somehow to update the socket?
2. Browser does some caching, service worker?

I hope someone can enlighten. This happens after upgrade to socket.io 4 from 2.

Answer (score 1):

It's my own stupidity.

My tenant who own the namespace. In order to reach him, I create his namespace and send message to it no matter he's online or offline.

This works fine in socket.io 2. I don't know why.

What I should do, is to check whether or not, the namespace exists or not first.

That's why the issue that I have is that the server somehow seems able to pipe message to the namespace, yet the tenant cannot send the message to the server because the tenant was not initialized properly in the nest gateway.